# list index out of range even with the correct output?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a simple program called "go fish" for a class.

```
player1Hand = [2, 4, 6, 8, "J", "Q", "K"]
player2Hand = [3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, "A"]
player1Guesses = [2, 8, "J", 4, "Q"]
player2Guesses = [6, 9, "A", 5, 3]
```

basically there are 5 turns (10 total outputs). If player 1 guess is in the player  2 hand then i am supposed to output "HERE'S MY CARD" and "GO FISH" if the card is not in the hand and vice versa. I got it work, but i keep getting a out of index error.

```
for i in range(20):
    if player1Guesses[i] in player2Hand:
        print ("HERE'S MY CARD")
    else:
        print ("GO FISH")
    if player2Guesses[i] in player1Hand:
        print ("HERE'S MY CARD")
    else:
        print("GO FISH")
```

I have tried changing the range to 21 and 19 but i still get the same error and output.

```
GO FISH
HERE'S MY CARD
GO FISH
GO FISH
GO FISH
GO FISH
HERE'S MY CARD
GO FISH
GO FISH
GO FISH
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Allen\Dropbox\Computer Science\GoFish.py", line 8, in <module>
    if player1Guesses[i] in player2Hand:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am getting the correct input that i need but for some reason it still says that the index is out of range. Why am a getting this error even when the program works? I'm also a bit new to coding and if you see any thing easier or simpler I can do with my code feel free to point it out! Thanks in advance!

- avbirm

Comment: `range(20)` will throw IndexError, all your lists length are smaller than 10

Comment: you should use range(5) because you have only 5 turns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
for i in range(20):
    if player1Guesses[i] in player2Hand:
```

You iterate over 20 items (0 to 19), but only have 5 in your list:

```
player1Guesses = [2, 8, "J", 4, "Q"]
```

Changing to `range(5)` will not throw the error, alternatively you can check if `i` is smaller than the length of `player1Guesses` as well as the check you are currently doing. Same goes for `player2Guesses`.

Comment: Okay, that makes so much more sense! I was confused because the program was working, but i kept getting that error. The code was working fine but i was just iterating over it too many times. I entered 5 as the range and it worked! I will check this response. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check whether i is a valid index or not, value of i must be smaller than the length of list.

```
player1Hand = [2, 4, 6, 8, "J", "Q", "K"]
player2Hand = [3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, "A"]
player1Guesses = [2, 8, "J", 4, "Q"]
player2Guesses = [6, 9, "A", 5, 3]

for i in range(20):
    if i < len(player1Guesses) and player1Guesses[i] in player2Hand:
        print ("HERE'S MY CARD")
    else:
        print ("GO FISH")
    if i < len(player2Guesses) and player2Guesses[i] in player1Hand:
        print ("HERE'S MY CARD")
    else:
        print("GO FISH")
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over actual length of your list:

```
length_of_list = len(player1Guesses)
for i in range(length_of_list):
if player1Guesses[i] in player2Hand:
    print ("HERE'S MY CARD")
```